# Android jetpack compose text colour is changed after animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have two Boxes, each of them has two AnimatedVisibility. Each AnimatedVisibility contains Text. Also I have a button, which triggers the animation (one text slides out, the other slides in). The problem I'm facing is that in dark mode, after animation, text colour is white, despite setting it to `Color.Black`. No clue how to fix it, or if it is some Xiaomi problem or what :(

```
    AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = box1TextToSlideInVisibility,
    enter = slideInVertically(
        animationSpec = tween(animationDuration)
    ) { height -> height },
    exit = slideOutVertically(
        animationSpec = tween(animationDuration)
    ) { height -> height }
) {
    Text(
        text = SOQuestion.FIRST.soName,
        color = Color.Black
    )
}
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = box1TextToSlideOutVisibility,
    enter = slideInVertically(
        animationSpec = tween(animationDuration)
    ) { height -> height },
    exit = slideOutVertically(
        animationSpec = tween(animationDuration)
    ) { height -> height }
) {
    Text(
        text = SOQuestion.SECOND.soName,
        color = Color.Black
    )
}
```

> after animation screen

[image]

> before animation screen

[image]

Also it doesn't matter if I add `color` in `Text` or in `style`.
The problem I've found occurs on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 & 10 Pro. On another Xiaomi/Samsungs it doesn't appear.

Comment: any luck on this